Why is this list slice 100x slower than using basic arithmetic?
I have two basic functions, one called first_valid_position that runs a binary search to find the first instance of a target value in a list. It is called in another function called totalValid. The code for this is below with the two options that I am using to compare speed.
 def totalValid(list1: list[int], list2: list[int], success: int) -> list[int]:
    list2.sort()
    solution = []
    
    for x in list1:
        solution.append(len(list2) - first_valid_position(list2, success, x)) #option 1
        solution.append(len(list2[first_valid_position(list2, success, x):])) #option 2
    return solution

As you can see, all this code does is calculate the first position of a target value in a sorted list2, and then calculate the number of entries in list2 after that target index based on each value in list1. The two solutions calculate an equivalent answer, but using a list slice to create a "temporary" list that is then fed into len() took ~13s while just calculating manually with arithmetic (option #1) took only 0.13s. Is creating this "temporary" list that slow? The lists for this comparison were both large, 100,000 entries each. I knew that straight arithmetic is obviously going to be faster but didn't expect it to be by such a huge magnitude. Why is the list slice version so much slower?

They are not equivalent. One is calling self.first_valid_position, the other without the self.

My apologies, that was a leftover piece that shouldn't have been there. Fixed now

Also, there is no list comprehension here.

I guess it ends up copying the slice so it can then call len on that; but check with dis

Oh wow, I have been programming for 4 hours now so my brain is completely melted, I meant slice and not comprehension. Fixed also

The slice operation has to create and populate a new list.  That takes time.

I figured it would add time, maybe 2-3x more. But 10x seemed a bit extreme to me. I may just be underestimating the time cost of copying

Option 2 involves list slicing. List slice creates a new list, so it needs memory allocation and copying, and since it is in a loop, and I think your lists are large, your option 2 involves massive memory allocation and copying. You must avoid such things if you can.
In option 1, there is no memory allocation and copying. It is much lighter than option 2.

Also, since the len() is now static, Python can probably avoid calling it again altogether.
